# How to get data from Prometheus DB, using Node.js

Tags: node.js, database, angular6, prometheus

How to get data from Prometheus DB, using Node.js

const client = require('prom-client');

I'm find this, but I.cant known how to connect to Prometheus Db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let RequestClient = require("reqclient").RequestClient;

let GetGlobalDataPrometeus = new RequestClient({
    baseUrl: "http://someUrlToPromDB.***.org/api/v1/",
 });

 module.exports = GetGlobalDataPrometeus;
```

and in another file in Api call

```
const GetGlobalDataPrometeus = require('../utils/***/prometeus');

GetGlobalDataPrometeus.get(`/query?query=${query}`)
        .then(response => {
            // console.log(response);
            resolve(response);

        })
        .catch(err => {
            reject(err)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

In January 2020, it looks like no one implemented a Prometheus querying client in NodeJS yet.

[Using the Prometheus REST API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/) with a random HTTP client works but it's not perfect.